# OpenGL context selection in wxPython application on linux

Tags: python, linux, opengl, wxpython

I have a wxpython program which uses two separate OpenGL windows (or more specifically two separate tabs in a notebook). Each window has it's own instance of `wx.glcanvas.GLCanvas`. On MS Windows, the two windows behave independently, as would be expected. On linux, however, opengl commands issued in one window seem to effect the other in a not entirely obvious way (some bits draw on one window, some on the other and some not at all, with lighting and alpha blending settings seeming to be applied to both. I'm calling `SetCurrent` in the `OnPaint` handler  of each of the canvases before issuing any OpenGL commands which *should* direct them to the current window and context. Noteably this does seem to work on windows.

I've got a nVidia graphics card if that is likely to make a difference.

Comment: I can now add that the contexts behave as expected if within two separate frames in the same app, it's just two separate tabs / children of the same parent frame where there is a problem.